# I'd like to use a MATLAB toolbox. Do I need Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'd like to use the Data Signal Processing toolbox in MATLAB, if I buy a MATLAB license and the toolbox, do I need to buy Simulink too?

What exactly does Simulink do? (In layman's terms.)

Comment: For any/all of [The MathWorks products](https://www.mathworks.com/products/alphabetical.html) you can look at its/their dependencies on other products by clicking the product of interest e.g. [The Signal Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/signal.html) and scroll down to where it says "This Product requires:".

Comment: That’d be helpful, now wouldn’t it? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to buy Simulink for that.
Layman terms... Simulink is kind of a graphical programming interface, where code is seen in terms of little boxes.